# Is it okay to specify return type in function prototype and not in function definition in c?

Tags: c, function, return-value, return-type

Can we specify the return type in just the function declaration and not in the function definition or does it have to be there in both ?

Comment: If you doesn't specify declaration type it's defaulted to `int`. But I guess the compiler would have gave you the same information in the form of a warning if you have tried compiling some test code.

Comment: If you read [the notes in this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#Notes), it will tell you that return type was optional in the C89 standard (and earlier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the return type in both, and the return types have to match.

As a special case, in earlier versions of C you could omit the return type if it were `int`, but this is no longer allowed (as of C99).